# Finding index values where a Series value changes significantly

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame read from a csv log file. One of the columns that I am studying is Fan Speed. There were several fan speed step changes during the log. I want to automatically find the last index of each Fan Speed Change Step for the entire log. How should I approach this ? I am new to python. Some guidance are appreciated !

Regards[image]

ffl3883

Answer (score 1):

You can get a series of *changes* in Series values using [`Series.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html).  Then, you could compare the absolute value of those changes to some tolerance that you choose.

```
STEP_CHANGE_TOLERANCE = 2500
idx = df[df["SYS_FAN_0_0"].diff().abs() > STEP_CHANGE_TOLERANCE].index
```

The code above will give the first (I think) index value of each new speed.  If you want the *last* index of each region, you could try:

```
idx_fwd = df[df["SYS_FAN_0_0"].diff(-1).abs() > STEP_CHANGE_TOLERANCE].index
```